# How to add a Android Target in Xamarin Mac Version

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to add a Android Target in Xamarin Mac Version ios Project ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an Android target to an iOS project.  If you also want to build an Android app, and an Android project to your solution.